# plotting a large number of dataframe columns with colormap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have an issue when plotting a large number of columns (>50) that it is difficult to distinguish between the series due to repetition in the default colors. Following directions at (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/visualization.html) I have tried to plot my data with the `colormap= argument` from matplotlib however I an returned the following error:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property colormap
```

My code is simple.

```
plt.plot(dfModel, linewidth=2.5, colormap='jet')
```

I would like my plot to look like this:
[image: Colormaps plot from matplotlib]

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas' `plot` with `cmap` option, which should also be the case for `plt.plot`, not `colormap`:

```
df.plot(cmap='jet')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried the cmap option also and return the same error, albeit with cmap and not colormap.

Comment: Do NOT use `plt.plot(df)`, use `df.plot(cmap='jet')`.

Comment: aaaaah. OK. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `cmap` parameter instead of `colormap`.

Check the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter).

Error:

```
Unknown property xxxx
```

Error means the property or parameter name is not defined.

Comment: Thanks Ruturaj, I have tried that already (see my response to Quang Hoang)